# why capacitor accumulate less charge in higher frequency

Tags: capacitor, ac, frequency, charge

it always said that the higher the frequency, the less charge will accumulate
because when in higher frequency, there is less time for capacitor to accumulate electrons.
and in lower frequency, there will be more time for capacitor to accumulate electrons.

but in higher frequency, although the time for accumulating is less but the current is larger
so how to conclude that in higher frequency, the total charge accumulated in capacitor is small ?

Comment: Please provide a reference for "it always said" claim. It does sound wrong as stated in your question.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev      http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/reactance62.php
The lower the frequency of the applied voltage, the more time the capacitor has to reach the fully charged, zero current state before the voltage reverses its polarity and begins to discharge the capacitor again. The capacitor therefore spends more time fully charged and passing much less current, the average value of current flow is therefore less at low frequencies. When a higher frequency is applied, the capacitor changes from charging to discharging sooner in its charge curve

Comment: This writeup has a lot of inaccuracies. I stopped reading after the line where it says the capacitor never reaches zero current on AC.

Comment: Why do you say the current is larger?

Comment: In every circuit you have real *resistance* which will limit the maximum current to some value *independent* of the frequency. At higher frequencies this fixed maximum current has less time to charge the capacitor, so the cap cannot accumulate as much charge before starting to discharge again.

Comment: Q=CV regardless of frequency

Answer (score -1):

No, Capacitor will store more charge at higher frequencies since, its Capacitive
Reactance is low for higher frequencies than the lower one. So the capacitor gets charged faster and outputs more current in the circuit when it discharges.

At lower frequencies, capacitive Reactance is high so that current entering into the capacitor is low. This is why capacitor takes more time to charge and outputs less current when it discharges.

To say simply, frequency is inversely proportional to reactance and directly proportional to current.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but as it is written now is sounds like you claim that more electrons reach the cap if the time is shorter.

Comment: From your comment, I can understand that capacitive reactance is nothing to do with current. IS it? or I did understand in a wrong way?

Comment: the electrons accumulated depend on the time of charging and also the charging current , so if the current is constant, shorter charging time leads to less electrons charged.  but if charging current is increased by higher frequency, shorter charging time can also lead to be more electrons accumulated, so why in higher frequency, the voltage across on capacitor(electrons charge ) is lower while there is larger charging current?

Comment: May be due to power factor. P = V x I. Is this correct?

Comment: I think we're mashing up things here. There is the amount of *charge* in the capacitor (Q). Then there is something like the "absoulte" current determined by voltage and reactance (and hence frequency). Then there is the "instantaneous" current which depends on voltage and ohmic resistance.

Comment: So, at higher frequencies you get more charge/discharge cycles per time unit, hence more electrons flowing back and forth per time unit (i.e. higher absolute current). However, to fully charge the capacitor takes infinite time, so the less time you have the less charges are transferred to or from the cap. I can charge the cap to 99.999% in 1s, but maybe only to 50% in 10ms, (depending on the series resistance, or impedance of the voltage source). Yet, 100x 50% charge is much more than 1x 99.999% charge, so the amount of charge *transferred* per time unit is larger at higher frequencies.

Comment: The amount of electrons "stored" in the cap (Q) is of course higer after 1s of applied voltage than it is after only 10ms.

Comment: @JimmyB .By your comment, Can I assume that my answer is correct?

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking at very very high frequencies capacitors will only get charged like 1-2% because there isnt enough time for electrons to overlay on one of the plates. This means that in every period 1/f, the voltage drop in the capacitor will be negligible. Therefore we can conclude that in very high frequencies capacitors act like a copper wire.

Comment: Can you back this up with some supporting equations? I think you are making assumptions that are not stated.

Comment: This is an approximate answer that provides some intuition about what’s going on, but some assumptions are made, namely that the charging current is held to a fixed limit, or that the voltage source used to drive the capacitor is imperfect. If you want a high frequency, high current source, couple the capacitor to the output of a waveguide fed from a decent magnetron. They will charge as much as possible before exploding :)